# OS X experiencing failure at long sleep

Tags: macos

At one point, my Macbook Pro (Late-2011 13 in. ver) started experiencing this issue every time it tries to wake up from a long sleep (longer than 1hr approximately). It fails to wake, and reboots instead, showing the pop-up that the os has shut down unexpectedly. It runs on a new SSD which replaced the old HDD.

I am trying to figure out if this is a hardware issue, or a configuration issue. One question that has arised on the way is about the hibernatemode value, which my OSX indicates 25. Is this a possible value?

When I ran `pmset -g` it showed the following:

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1*
AC Power        -1
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              0
 halfdim              1
 sms                  1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10
 hibernatemode        25
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         2
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reset the SMC and NVRAM?

> **To reset the SMC:**
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Plug in the MagSafe or USB-C power adapter to a power source and to your computer.
> 3. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
> 4. Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
> 5. Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Source : Apple KB - [Resetting the System Management Controller (SMC) on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201295)

> **To reset the NVRAM (PRAM)**
>
> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R.
> 3. Turn on your Mac.
> 4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you hear the startup sound.
> 5. Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for a second time.
> 6. Release the keys.

Source : Apple KB - [How to Reset NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)